# Why isn't this code causing a ConcurrentModificationException?

Tags: java, iterator, concurrentmodification

I was reading about ConcurrentModificationException and how to avoid it. Found [an article](http://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/05/avoid-concurrentmodificationexception.html). The first listing in that article had code similar to the following, which would apparently cause the exception:

```
List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
myList.add("January");
myList.add("February");
myList.add("March");

Iterator<String> it = myList.iterator();
while(it.hasNext())
{
    String item = it.next();
    if("February".equals(item))
    {
        myList.remove(item);
    }
}

for (String item : myList)
{
    System.out.println(item);
}
```

Then it went on to explain how to solve the problem with various suggestions.

When I tried to reproduce it, I didn't get the exception! **Why am I not getting the exception?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

According to the Java API docs [Iterator.hasNext](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext()) does not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`.

After checking `"January"` and `"February"` you remove one element from the list. Calling `it.hasNext()` does not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException` but returns false. Thus your code exits cleanly. The last String however is never checked. If you add `"April"` to the list you get the Exception as expected.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Iterator;

public class Main {
        public static void main(String args[]) {

                List<String> myList = new ArrayList<String>();
                myList.add("January");
                myList.add("February");
                myList.add("March");
                myList.add("April");

                Iterator<String> it = myList.iterator();
                while(it.hasNext())
                {
                    String item = it.next();
                    System.out.println("Checking: " + item);
                    if("February".equals(item))
                    {
                        myList.remove(item);
                    }
                }

                for (String item : myList)
                {
                    System.out.println(item);
                }

        }
}
```

http://ideone.com/VKhHWN

Comment: You've explained what's happening just fine, but not **why**. And the why is: Its a bug in `ArrayList`'s iterator class.

Comment: Doesn´t answer the question. But not a bug as TJ says either.

Comment: I was confused at first but after adding the print statement inside the while-loop it became clear. The API docs of [`Iterator.hasNext`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/Iterator.html#hasNext()) do not state that an `ConcurrentModificationException` is thrown so it really works as designed. It is a bit counter intuitive and to be true, I would expect `hasNext` to throw in those cases. This check was probably left out for performance reasons.

Comment: I just added a reference to the API docs in my answer. It works as designed. `hasNext` does not throw but also does not return `true` in this case either. So it explains the behaviour and answers the question.

Comment: *"According to the Java API docs Iterator.hasNext does not throw a `ConcurrentModificationException`."* **Facepalm** +1, deleted my answer. That is SERIOUSLY wrong, but clearly documented. :-)

Comment: Actually, even `Iterator.next()` does not declare to throw CME. Only the JavaDoc for the whole `ArrayList` class says: _if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException_, but no concrete method is specified.

Comment: Why ```if("March".equals(item)) myList.remove(item);``` still throws exception?

Answer (score 5):

From `ArrayList` source (JDK 1.7):

```
private class Itr implements Iterator<E> {
    int cursor;       // index of next element to return
    int lastRet = -1; // index of last element returned; -1 if no such
    int expectedModCount = modCount;

    public boolean hasNext() {
        return cursor != size;
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public E next() {
        checkForComodification();
        int i = cursor;
        if (i >= size)
            throw new NoSuchElementException();
        Object[] elementData = ArrayList.this.elementData;
        if (i >= elementData.length)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        cursor = i + 1;
        return (E) elementData[lastRet = i];
    }

    public void remove() {
        if (lastRet < 0)
            throw new IllegalStateException();
        checkForComodification();

        try {
            ArrayList.this.remove(lastRet);
            cursor = lastRet;
            lastRet = -1;
            expectedModCount = modCount;
        } catch (IndexOutOfBoundsException ex) {
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
        }
    }

    final void checkForComodification() {
        if (modCount != expectedModCount)
            throw new ConcurrentModificationException();
    }
}
```

Every modifying operation on an `ArrayList` increments the `modCount` field (the number of times the list has been modified since creation).

When an iterator is created, it stores the current value of `modCount` into `expectedModCount`. The logic is:

- if the list isn't modified at all during the iteration, `modCount == expectedModCount`
- if the list is modified by the iterator's own `remove()` method, `modCount` is incremented, but `expectedModCount` gets incremented as well, thus `modCount == expectedModCount` still holds
- if some other method (or even some other iterator instance) modifies the list, `modCount` gets incremented, therefore `modCount != expectedModCount`, which results in `ConcurrentModificationException`

However, as you can see from the source, the check isn't performed in `hasNext()` method, only in `next()`. The `hasNext()` method also only compares the current index with the list size. When you removed the second-to-last element from the list (`"February"`), this resulted that the following call of `hasNext()` simply returned `false` and terminated the iteration before the CME could have been thrown.

However, if you removed any element other than second-to-last, the exception would have been thrown.

Answer (score 2):

I think the correct explanation is this extract from the javadocs of ConcurrentModificationExcetion:

> Note that fail-fast behavior cannot be guaranteed as it is, generally
>   speaking, impossible to make any hard guarantees in the presence of
>   unsynchronized concurrent modification. Fail-fast operations throw
>   ConcurrentModificationException on a best-effort basis. Therefore, it
>   would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for
>   its correctness: ConcurrentModificationException should be used only
>   to detect bugs.

So, if the iterator is fail fast it may throw the exception but there´s no guarantee. Try replacing `February` with `January` in your example and the exception is thrown (At least in my environment)

Comment: While that paragraph is there, note the caveats in it. Meanwhile, though, bikeshedder [gets to the crux of the matter](http://stackoverflow.com/a/14673738/157247): `hasNext` doesn't throw `ConcurrentModificationException`! In the face of that simple fact, all my analysis in my answer (and yours in ours) is by-the-bye.

Answer (score 0):

The iterator checks that it has iterated as many times as you have elements left to see it has reached the end before it checks for a concurrent modification.  This means if you remove only the second last element you don't see a CME in the same iterator.