# Expecting ConcurrentModificationException by deleting 2nd last element of ArrayList while iterating the same ArrayList

Tags: java

I am deleting 2nd last element of an ArrayList while iterating the same list through enhanced for-loop and I was expecting a ConcurrentModificationException however it is working fine. Kindly help me if java has provided a special case for 2nd last element.

I tried it with different indexes but it is working as expected only for the 2nd last element, it is giving unexpected result

```
    List<Integer> list=new ArrayList<>();
    list.add(2);
    list.add(4);
    list.add(3);
    list.add(5);
    for(Integer num:list) {
        if(num==3) {
            list.remove(num);
        }
        System.out.println(num);
    }
```

**Expected result:** ConcurrentModificationException

**Actual Result:** Working fine

Comment: The method that throws ConcurrentModificationException is the method ```Iterator#next``` that is being used with the syntax suggar ```for(Integer num : list)``` that will be actually replaced by ```Iterator<Integer> it = list.iterator(); while(it.hasNext()) num = it.next()``` there's something about hasNext returning false in the first situation. IDK

Comment: I agree that this is covered in https://stackoverflow.com/q/14673653/3182664 , and specifically the technical reason is explained in sufficient details in  https://stackoverflow.com/a/14674151/3182664  (i.e. not the accepted answer there). I'll close this one as a duplicate. If there are objections, drop me a note.

Comment: @Marco13 This question is not the same,can you  add your answer for it

Comment: it is definitively `hasNext` returning `false` before `next` can be called to throw the exception - just seen on debugger - the catch is that the for-each loop is transformed to a while loop using that methods

Comment: FWIW, according to my tests using JDK 12.0.1, it doesn't matter how long the `List` is, i.e. how many elements it contains, removing any element **except** for the second-last element throws `ConcurrentModificationException`.

Comment: @lucumt I think that https://stackoverflow.com/a/14674151/3182664 explains this pretty well: `next()` (which could throw) is called, then one element is removed, and the `for` loop basically only checks whether the end has been reached (by calling `hasNext`, which does *not* check the mod count or throw). I wonder which details should be added beyond that...?!

Comment: @Marco13 Thanks,I will check it further!

Comment: now the question is: does the iterator break the `ArrayList` contract? "* if the list is structurally modified at any time after the iterator is created, in any way except through the iterator's own remove or add methods, the iterator will throw a ConcurrentModificationException.*"

Comment: @CarlosHeuberger The next paragraph says "Note that the fail-fast behavior of an iterator cannot be guaranteed...", so I'd say "no", although one could certainly nitpick about the wording in view of the part that you quoted. Checking for a CME in the `hasNext` method is probably not worth the effort, usually...