# For java List concurrent modification exception not thrown if remove method invoked before iteration

Tags: java

The following code does not throw ConcurrentModificationException

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add("v1");
        Iterator<String> it =  l1.iterator();
        l1.remove(0);
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
```

Whereas this code throws ConcurrentModificationException

```
    public static void main(String[] args)
    {
        List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
        l1.add("v1");
        Iterator<String> it =  l1.iterator();
        l1.add("v2");
        while(it.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(it.next());
        }
    }
```

Both operations are structural modifications of list, but why exception is thrown only in case of addition?

Comment: When you remove the element the list is empty and the `Iterator` returned by `ArrayList` only checks the modification count when you call `next()`, not `hasNext()`. Maybe a bug?

Comment: yes i think you are right. if i add 2 elements, get the iterator and then remove one element and iterate, it throws the exception

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/57168307/85421 (and others that is duplicate from) - `hasNext()` does not throw that Exception, if `next()` is not called, no Exception will be thrown

Comment: Javadoc of [Iterator](https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/12/docs/api/java.base/java/util/Iterator.html): "Therefore, it would be wrong to write a program that depended on this exception for its correctness: *the fail-fast behavior of iterators should be used only to detect bugs*."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Look at `ArrayList.Itr`.

There're two counters: `ArrayList.modCount` and `ArrayList.Itr.expectedModCount`. `ArrayList.Itr` throws `ConcurrentModificationException` when `modCount != expectedModCount`.

This is correct. But if you look at `ArrayList.Itr.hasNext` you can see:

```
public boolean hasNext() {
    return cursor != size;
}
```

When you remove one element and you list become empty, then your code does not invoke `it.next()`.

To make your code throw `ConcurrentModificationException`, you should have not empty list before while loop:

```
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    List<String> l1 = new ArrayList<>();
    l1.add("v1");
    l1.add("v2");
    Iterator<String> it =  l1.iterator();
    l1.remove(0);
    while(it.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(it.next());  // --> ConcurrentModificationException
    }
}
```